# How to test if a SharePoint connect is successful with user credentials using Unit testing C#

Tags: unit-testing, c-sharp

I am working on a project where I am trying to test if a `user` has successfully logged in with valid credentials using the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll`.

Currently my code is checking the `HTTP` Response code for the SharePoint URL - however it is not checking to see if the `user` has passed in valid credentials.

For example - I can change my password, and the test will still pass since the code is only seeing if it is being passed a valid endpoint.

Is there a way with the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll to see if a user has provided proper credentials?

**Current Test**

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ConnectionToSharePoint_IsSuccessful()
    {
        var sharePointConnection = _sharePointService.OpenConnectionToSharePoint();
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest
            .Create(sharePointConnection.Url);
        var responce = (HttpWebResponse) webRequest.GetResponse();

        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK,responce.StatusCode);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look for Response Code. 401 means UnAuthorized and 403 means Forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

If  autentication is Form Based, onwrong credientals you will just be transfered on another page with error message or stay on the same page with http:200. You would need to check for particular html objects in the DOM as well.